# SSAS Processing via c# (Microsoft.AnalysisServices) Much Slower than SSMS

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, ssas, ssms

I am processing my SSAS Cube programmatically. I process the dimensions in parallel (I manage the parallel calls to .Process() myself) and once they're all finished, I process the measure group partitions in parallel (again managing the parallelism myself).

As far as I can see, this is a direct replication of what I would otherwise do in SSMS (same process types etc.) The only difference I can see is that I'm processing ALL of the dimensions in parallel and ALL of the measure group partitions in parallel thereafter. If you right click process several objects within SSMS, it appears to only process 2 in parallel at any one time (inferred from the text that indicates process has not started in all processing windows other than 2). But if anything, I would expect my code to be faster, not slower than SSMS.

I have wrapped the processing action with "starting" and "finishing" debug messages and everything is as expected. It is the work done by .Process() that seems to be much slower than SSMS.

On a Cube that normally takes just under 1 hour to process, it is taking 7.5 hours.
On a cube that normally takes just under 3 minutes to process, it is taking 6.5 minutes.
As far as I can tell, the processing of dimensions is about the same but the measure groups are significantly slower. However, the latter are much much larger of course so it might just be that the difference is not as obvious to me.

I'm at a loss for ideas and would appreciate any help! Am I missing a setting? Is managing the parallelism myself and processing multiple in parallel as opposed to 2 causing a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide your code I'm happy to look but my guess is that you are calling dimension.Process() in parallel threads expecting it to process in parallel on the server. It won't. It will process in serial due to locking because you are executing separate processing batches and separate transactions.

Any reason not to process everything (rather than incrementally processing just recent partitions or something)?  Let's start simple and see if this is all you need. Can you get the database object and just do a ProcessFull? That will properly process in parallel all dimensions and measure groups.

```
database.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull)
```

If you do need incremental processing then review this link for using ExecuteCaptureLog(true,true) to run multiple ProcessUpdate commands in parallel and in a transaction:
https://jesseorosz.wordpress.com/2006/11/20/how-to-process-dimensions-in-parallel-using-amo/

I would recommend including the partitions you want to process in that transactional batch. It will know the right dependencies automatically. Also make sure to include a ProcessIndexes on the cube object in that batch so flexible aggs and indexes on old partitions get rebuilt after the dimension ProcessUpdate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't believe I didn't think that the server would serialise my requests - unsurprising given it handles locks itself. Is there a function / property that allows me to process in parallel? I process update dimensions and then recent partitions - this is definitely all I need - it would too time consuming to process all (and unnecessary). The Cube is semi-aggregated but there are over 7bn rows sitting behind it. In SSMS, we right click process update all dimension and then right click process full recent partitions. Thanks again.

Comment: Greg, thank you so much. Really appreciate this - will implement this logic now and follow up. Such a niche issue that I was really struggling to find information for!